# Store NodeJS script outside of Docker container, so it can be modified

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm interested in running a NodeJS script inside a Docker container, because that seems to be the easiest way to run stuff in unRAID (small scripts at least).

My current Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM node:12.9.1

COPY app.js /home/node/
COPY package*.json /home/node/
RUN mkdir /home/node/saves

WORKDIR /home/node
RUN npm install

CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

Not perfect, but works well enough. What my script does, is that it scrapes certain websites for data, then places it in a folder called `saves`.

But because I do `COPY app.js /home/node/`, every time I want to make a tiny change to my `app.js` file, I need to rebuild the whole image, delete the container, and start a new one. Kind of irritating, but it has worked for me.. for now.

When I start my container, I want that volume to stay persistent, so I do this:

```
docker run --net=bridge -h scraper --name scraper -d -v /mnt/user/scripts/scraper/saves:/home/node/saves scraper
```

This works, but as I said, if I want to change my `app.js` (like add a new site to scrape), I have to rebuild the image and run the above command again. Every single time.

What's a better approach than this? I could solve this by not copying the files, but instead run `npm install` and then `node app.js` every time, but this script runs every 3 minutes, so that would be a huge waste of resources.

I could also store the appropriate data inside my /saves/ folder, then read that in the NodeJS script every time, but I feel like that's kind of a hack.

Comment: If app.js is the only thing that changes regularly, you can move that COPY step as your last step before CMD and it should be able to use cached layers to quickly rebuild the image.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use Environment variables.

If the type of changes to app.js file already known, you could
use environment variables to supply such changes to docker run, and
an entrypoint script file to make such modification using
environment variable.

The content of entrypoint script will depend on what you want to do.

```sh
# Add to your Dockerfile
ENV SITE_TO_SCRAP=example.com
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

# Run docker with 
-e SITE_TO_SCRAP=abc.com
```

Entry Point script may looks like

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Modify app.js
# Assuming changing the line SCRAP_URL="someurl"
sed -i -e "s@SCRAP_URL=\"someurl\"@SCRAP_URL=\"${SITE_TO_SCRAP}\"@" /home/node/app.js

# This will execute the CMD
exec "$@"
```

#### Make node cache folder persistent

To run `npm install` do it in entry point script not in docker file. make node.js cache folder persistent by mounting `-v host/path/to/cache:/root/.npm`. this way node install use cached files whenever possible. use `docker run --rm node:{version} npm config get cache` to get container cache directory.

#### Manually mount modified files.

```
# To your docker run command add required file/directory mount(s)
-v /path/to/modified/app.js:/home/node/app.js
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can't use environment variables, because it's not just an URL I use. It also has config stuff. I can't make the node_modules or cache persistent, as my host only knows Docker (and should only know Docker).